# Why does plasma cleaning (etching) takes longer time to be effective when there is a mask compared to when the entire surface in exposed?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics, air, gas

I have a substrate with some chemical bonded to it. I want to selectively etch the chemical in certain spots, hence I am using a mask with through-hole on top of the substrate, then exposing it to air plasma. I noticed that the when I expose the substrate to plasma, without adding the mask, it takes around 1 minute to get rid of the chemical layer. While when adding the mask, the etching happens much faster (~10-30sec). What could be the scientific explanation for this? What equation governs this phenomena? and how this might change with smaller/larger through-holes in the mask?

the schematics attached will help you to visualize the question.[image]

Comment: It is hard to say from that much information. An air plasma creates monoatomic oxygen which is very good at oxidizing some chemicals. For example, it will eat more or less anything organic. Perhaps the mask material interacts with the plasma and creates a chemical more suitable to etching whatever is on the substrate?

Comment: the mask material is Resin, and the chemical attached to the porous scaffold is silane

Answer (score 2):

Oxygen plasma descums a chemical layer by presenting the surface of that layer with monatomic oxygen and various highly reactive oxygen-containing ions. These chemically attack the layer and convert it into a gaseous product that your vacuum system can then scavenge; in the process, the reactive oxygen is consumed.

The rate at which you can descum a substrate with a plasma asher depends on how fast you make fresh plasma to replace what got eaten up, and how much surface area you have to descum. Turning up the RF power in the asher replenishes the oxygen species quickly, meaning faster ashing. Reducing the surface area means slower depletion of the oxygen, and the small area gets clobbered more quickly for a given power setting in the asher.

Comment: kind of makes sense. but here you're assuming that the oxygen doesn't interact with the mask at all, and is all reserved to interact with the chemical...right? is it a safe assumption? note that the mask is made of Resin and the chemical is silane coating.

Comment: Hm, this would depend on the ratio of etch rates between silane and photoresin. Why not ash with a fluoro compound instead of air? and are you using a barrel asher or a downstream device?

Comment: I'm using a vacuum plasma cleaner machine

Comment: Silane is SiH4, a gas similar to methane but with Si instead of C. It spontaneously ignites in air, producing SiO2 (glass or quartz). So something is odd about this. Is this just an adsorbed film? Why is an oxygen plasma needed instead of just O2? How does a vacuum pump scavenge SiO2? So are you sure the chemical being removed is Silane?

Comment: you're not going to ash off SiO2 in an air plasma; at most you will ash off photoresist residue from the photomask definition process.